# Impossible to edit inputs except the first of a ion list

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm a beginner in ionic. The app works well in Chromium. When android built, it's impossible to edit again the last 3 inputs if all the inputs have been filled.Here the html:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="danger">
<ion-title>Ajouter une seance</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>

<ion-item>
<ion-label fixed>Duree</ion-label>
<ion-input type="time" step="2" value="0" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label fixed>Date</ion-label>
<ion-input type="date" value="0"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
<ion-label fixed>Distance(km):</ion-label>
<ion-input type="number" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label fixed>FC moyenne</ion-label>
<ion-input type="number" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

It's probably obvious. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How you're going to bind the data? no `ngModel`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just starting learning ionic and I tried these ion-inputs but I would like to fix their behavior (to stay editable) before handling the data.

Comment: Remove `fixed` and see that.

Comment: Just tried but still the same problem. The first input can be corrected not the others.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution where the ion-inputs don't loose the focus and stay editable . I removed in the given code, the ion-header, ion-content and ion list tags. Now, it works perfectly with Android. But as a new user of ionic, I don't really understand what I loose by removing those tags.

UPDATE

I finally found a solution:
in the scss, add:

```
.input-cover {

   position: static;

}
```

Now the input are always focusable and I can use ion-content, ion-header.

Comment: Wow, not only did this fix the issue but it also fixes an issue where they keyboard would cover the input on select.  Nice find!

Comment: Yes!  This is the fix I've been looking for -- for a year!

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the `padding` as shown below.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label fixed>Distance(km):</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" text-right></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I tried. There's a change: now it's the second ion-input that can be edited but the first, third and four are disabled.

Comment: sorry no improvement. Got to stop for the moment. Thanks for the help. Will try to solve later